# Use Map function with subsets of a pandas series or dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, apply

Lets say I have a pandas.Dataframe that looks as follows:

```
c1 | c2
-------
 1 | 5 
 2 | 6 
 3 | 7 
 4 | 8
 .....
 1 | 7
```

and I'm looking to map a function (`DataFrame.corr`) but I would like it to take `n` rows at a time.  The result should be a series with the correlation values that would be shorter than the original DataFrame or with a few values that didn't get a full `n` rows of data.

Is there a way to do this and how? I've been looking through the DataFrame and Map, Apply, Filter documentation but it doesn't seem to have an obvious or clean solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With pandas 0.20, using `rolling` with `corr` produces a multi indexed dataframe.  You can slice afterwards to get at what you're looking for.

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
np.random.seed([3,1415])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(10, 2)), columns=['c1', 'c2'])

   c1  c2
0   0   2
1   7   3
2   8   7
3   0   6
4   8   6
5   0   2
6   0   4
7   9   7
8   3   2
9   4   3
```

**`rolling` + `corr`... `pandas 0.20.x`**

```
df.rolling(5).corr().dropna().c1.xs('c2', level=1)
# Or equivalently
# df.rolling(5).corr().stack().xs(['c1', 'c2'], level=[1, 2])

4    0.399056
5    0.399056
6    0.684653
7    0.696074
8    0.841136
9    0.762187
Name: c1, dtype: float64
```

**`rolling` + `corr`... `pandas 0.19.x` or prior**
Prior to 0.20, `rolling` + `corr` produced a `pd.Panel`

```
df.rolling(5).corr().loc[:, 'c1', 'c2'].dropna()

4    0.399056
5    0.399056
6    0.684653
7    0.696074
8    0.841136
9    0.762187
Name: c2, dtype: float64
```

---

**`numpy` + `as_strided`**
However, I wasn't satisfied with the above answers.  Below is a specialized function that takes an `nx2` dataframe and returns a series of the rolling correlations.  **DISCLAIMER** This uses some advanced techniques and should really only be used if you know what this does.  Meaning if you need a detailed breakdown of how this works... then it probably isn't for you.

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided as strided

def rolling_correlation(a, w):
    n, m = a.shape[0], 2
    s1, s2 = a.strides
    b = strided(a, (m, w, n - w + 1), (s2, s1, s1))
    b_mb = b - b.mean(1, keepdims=True)
    b_ss = (b_mb ** 2).sum(1) ** .5
    return (b_mb[0] * b_mb[1]).sum(0) / (b_ss[0] * b_ss[1])

def rolling_correlation_df(df, w):
    a = df.values
    return pd.Series(rolling_correlation(a, w), df.index[w-1:])

rolling_correlation_df(df, 5)

4    0.399056
5    0.399056
6    0.684653
7    0.696074
8    0.841136
9    0.762187
dtype: float64
```

---

**Timing**
*small data*

```
%timeit rolling_correlation_df(df, 5)
10000 loops, best of 3: 79.9 µs per loop

%timeit df.rolling(5).corr().stack().xs(['c1', 'c2'], level=[1, 2])
100 loops, best of 3: 14.6 ms per loop
```

*large data*

```
np.random.seed([3,1415])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(10000, 2)), columns=['c1', 'c2'])

%timeit rolling_correlation_df(df, 5)
1000 loops, best of 3: 615 µs per loop

%timeit df.rolling(5).corr().stack().xs(['c1', 'c2'], level=[1, 2])
1 loop, best of 3: 1.98 s per loop
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!! Thanks